# Flutter Sharding Test still take same time as Serial

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, gitlab-ci

I am creating a parallel Flutter unit test on GitLab CI to avoid 60 minutes run-time limit.

The initial command was

```
flutter test --machine --coverage ./lib > test-report.jsonl
```

The process took around 59 minutes because we have a lot of unit tests.

In order to reduce the CI pipeline time, I modify the pipeline to be parallel using flutter shard and GitLab CI parallel feature.

The command is like this

```
      flutter test \
        --total-shards $CI_NODE_TOTAL \
        --shard-index $( expr $CI_NODE_INDEX - 1 ) \
        --machine \
        --coverage \
        --coverage-path coverage/lcov.info-$( expr $CI_NODE_INDEX - 1 ) \
        ./lib \
        > test-report.jsonl-$( expr $CI_NODE_INDEX - 1 )
```

However, all the parallel jobs still run more than a 60-minute time limit.

[image]

[image]

What did I miss or how to debug it?

Comment: I am also looking at this on gitlab CI. If you don't mind can you share your gitlab job?

Also based on documentation I think you need to give path of the tests for each shard https://pub.dev/packages/test#sharding-tests 

Our tests are taking 45 mins, I will give this a shot and let you know. I saw the gitlab parallel thing but not sure if it really know how to use flutter shards